# gzip several files in different directories and copy to new directory

Tags: linux, compression, gzip

I'm working with several files that are located in different directories that I need to compress into individual .gz files. I also need to move the compressed files to a single directory while leaving the originals alone.

Is there a way to do this using the gzip command and a file that contains a list of all the file paths of the files I want to compress?

Apologies if that's a bit long-winded...I'm fairly new to Linux and can't think of a more efficient way of wording this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the list of files is stored in a file called *filelist* (exactly one file path per line) and you want to store the compressed files in *zipdir*, this bash script will achieve the desired results:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read file; do
    gzip -c "$file" > "zipdir/$(basename "$file").gz"
done < filelist
```

In bash/dash, you can also convert the above to a one-liner:

```
while IFS= read file; do gzip -c "$file" > "zipdir/$(basename "$file").gz"; done < filelist
```

In other shells (e.g., tcsh or zsh)

```
bash -c 'while IFS= read file; do gzip -c "$file" > "zipdir/$(basename "$file").gz"; done < filelist'
```

will do the job.

If bash isn't present, it can be substituted with dash.

#### How it works

- `...  < filelist` redirects the contents of *filelist* to `...`.
- `while IFS= read file; do ... done` goes through the lines in filelist, stores the contents of the currently processed line in the variable *file* and executes `...`.

  `IFS=` modifies the internal file separator. This is needed to handle multiple, leading and trailing spaces properly.
- `gzip -c "$file" > "zipdir/$(basename "$file").gz"` compressed the currently processed file and stores the output in a file with the same name plus an *.gz* extension in the directory *zipdir*.

  Here `basename "$file"` extracts the bare filename from the file's path.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! It looks like it's on the right track of where I want to go. However, the person I work for prefers tcsh (I think that's what they learned on) and so the box I work on runs in that shell. Is there any way to write this so it will work in tcsh?

Comment: Porting the above to tcsh shouldn't be too hard, but I don't nearly enough tcsh to do so. As long as bash is install, it suffices to save the above to a script and add a bash shebang or invoke it with `bash -c`.

Comment: OK, awesome. I'll give that a try. Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: Just tried this and everything works perfectly! However, I have one more question. When the end of my flist is reached (after all other files are successfully copied/compressed), the script keeps trying to read further down the flist, but since there are no file paths left it just makes a blank .gz file and gives me an error of "no such file or directory." Is there anything I can add to the end of my flist to tell the script that it's reached the end?

Comment: The script is whitespace-sensitive. If there's a line at the end that has a single space on it, it will create a ` .gz` file (note leading space). An empty line (not even containing a space) will result in a similar error but no empty file.

Comment: Again, thanks! I have one more question and then I think I can leave you alone. Based on your explanation of the script you wrote above, I thought that if I just wanted to copy several files from multiple directories to a single directory, but not gzip them, I could simply replace "gzip -c" with "cp." However, that didn't work. I got an error stating "missing destination file operand after /source/directories" for every file I have in the flist. Any pointers on how I could accomplish only copying several files from an flist to a single directory?

Comment: `gzip` writes to stdout; `cp` does not. `cp` requires the destination as a second argument, so all you have to do is drop the "greater-than sign". Use `cp "$file" destination`.

Comment: Everything works perfectly, you have saved me hours of mindless file copying! Thanks again for all your help and patience.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `gzip` supports reading paths from a file. The workaround would be to either put all the target files into an archive (tar) or execute it several times.

If the target directory isn't limited with regard to capacity or transfer speed, a possible solution would be to move the files before compressing them in the target folder as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766284/rsync-read-input-from-a-file-and-sync-accordingly).

Otherwise, you would read a single file name at a time, compressing and creating their folders as you go.

**Create folder structure**

```
TARGET=~/tmp/out

while read line; do 
    dirname "$line" ; 
done < list.txt | sort -u |
xargs -I%  echo mkdir -p "$TARGET/%"

  ## out: ##
  mkdir /home/jaroslav/tmp/out/code/bash 
  mkdir /home/jaroslav/tmp/out/recipes
  mkdir /home/jaroslav/tmp/out/samba
  mkdir /home/jaroslav/tmp/out/wikipedia
```

**Copy files**

```
while read line; do
   gzip -c "$SOURCE/$line" > "$TARGET/$line.gz"
done < list.txt
```

**Commands**

- dirname: remove the last part of a filepath, leaving the directory
- read [arg] < file: read one line at a time from file and store it in the shell variable arg
- sort -u: remove duplicate entries (leave `u`nique)
- xargs -I% : execute a command (echo ....) once for every element (dir name) from the pipe (|)
- gzip -c in > out: compress in and write to stdout (-c). > redirects stdin to a file named out.